# WPF showdialog window After that accidental touch and firing event

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, touch-event, showdialog

I have a problem in my WPF application. We have a parent wpf page and we start a dialog via showDialog method then after this dialog window closed, if we touch any point regardless that it is an item or empty position, the last focused element in parent window fires an its touch event even if we do not touch it.

How can I figure that problem out? It is really annoying issue.

I expect that after a child window closed, if I touch an empty area of main parent window, accidental touch event which belongs items on main window should not fire its event, because I do not touch that item, I only touch empty area

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2491